# Python 2.x Поддержка esmtp на сервере

Tags: python, python-2.x, smtp, smtp-server

Добрый день.
Развёрнут сервер CentOS 6.6, на борту предустановленный Python 2.6.6.
Пару лет назад мною был написан небольшой асинхронный почтовый псевдо сервер, который просто принимал сообщение, парсил заголовки почтового сообщения, добавлял их в базу данных mysql и клал файл сообщения на жесткий диск.
В качестве SMTP-сенсора выступает стандартная библиотека smtpd.
Работает всё очень просто:

```
import smtpd
import asyncore
from datetime import datetime
import random
import string

class mySMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        # parse headers
        #-----код вырезан-----

        # write to database
        #-----код вырезан-----

        # save message
        # create token 6 symbols
        token = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for x in range(6))

        f = open('Inbox/'+datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')[:-3]+'.'+token+'.eml', 'w')
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
        return

server = mySMTPServer((myhost, myport), None)

asyncore.loop()
```

На код можно и не смотреть. Не суть.

Проблема в том, что теперь мне нужно принимать сообщения по ESMTP. Насколько я понял, стандартная библиотека smtpd в python-2.x не поддерживает ESMTP ?
Принять этот факт как данное?
Как то не хочется переходить под python3, тем более, что при парсинге большое внимание было уделено кодировкам (вечные проблемы, которые более менее удалось минимизировать).

Чем заменить smtpd, если его нельзя заставить работать по ESMTP в Python версии 2.x?

Comment: проверить поддержку esmtp просто: послать ehlo команду и посмотреть какие расширения поддерживаются. smtpd в Питоне 2 совсем не поддерживает, в Питоне 3 -- по крайней мере  какие-то расширения поддерживаются. В Питоне 3, документация рекомендует `aiosmtpd`.